# Manually initialize a singleton which has Dependence Injected parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, singleton

My environment is, Asp.net5, MVC6. I'm tring to use SingalR to broadcast some server side information to clients periodically. I create a "Braodcaster" like this,

```
public class ServerInfoHub : Hub
{

}

public class Broadcaster
{
    private readonly Timer looper;
    private readonly IHubContext hubContext;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    private readonly PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
    private static Broadcaster instance;

    public Broadcaster(IHubContext hubContext)
    {
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        looper = new Timer(new TimerCallback(onTimer), this, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }

    private void onTimer(object target)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(ramCounter.NextValue(), cpuCounter.NextValue());
    }
}
```

And make it ("Broadcaster") as a singleton by doing so at Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //ignored unrelated code
        services.AddSingleton(_ => new Broadcaster(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerInfoHub>()));
    }
```

While, I want this "Broadcaster" get initialized when the Application is launching. While, the "Broadcaster" has no other module that is depending on it, and the "Braodcaster" is depending on "IHubContext", which means I may not able to create a static 'CreateInstance' method in 'Broadcaster' and call it straight forward at Startup.cs, which is something like this

```
public class Broadcaster
{
 private static Broadcaster instance;


    public static void CreateInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Broadcaster(???);
        }
    }

    private Broadcaster(IHubContext hubContext) {}
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you really have to create a Singleton Broadcaster? What's the cost if you create a non-Singleton i.e per request/resolve Broadcaster?

Comment: Hi Spock, the Broadcaster is Singleton as it keeps running, Note that Broadcaster has a timer in it, it's duty is to broadcaster some message to all connected clients (SignalR clients) by a certain time period basis. If it is a non-Singleton, but based on request, I think it cannot do broadcasting in a definite rate.